# Making ExtJS Window maximize animated?

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

My question is simple: is there a way to animate the maximize of ExtJS windows? Currently my windows just maximize without any animation and it looks "boring".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Ext.Fx`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Fx) may be capable of doing what you're asking for.  I was particularly thinking of the `scale()` function.  It also provides other options for animation manipulation, like style changes.  It seems like the most likely way to do what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Animal has given some instructions on this in the ExtJS Forums:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?70764#post341558